# How are private transactions possible?

Tags: private, flashbots, private-transaction

I'm curious about the origin of private transactions (how are they even possible, who came up with them) and how they work.
Also, are private pools the same as relay services?
Why have they gained significance recently?

I'm eager to learn more.

Comment: What do you mean by "private transactions"? Everything in Ethereum is public. Perhaps, you wanted to ask about some L2 chain?

Comment: Hey pls have a look here: https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/ethereum-private-transactions
Also, this paper might help: An Empirical Study on Ethereum Private Transactions and the Security Implications

Answer (score 0):

There are not such things as private transaction on the Ethereum blockchain.

Some services allow sending transaction through their system without exposing them in the pending transaction pool. The transaction will be public once they are mined. They are only "private" for a short time until they are published in a block.